# RedBean with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, redbean

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedBean_Exception_Security' with message 'OODB Store requires a bean, got:  string' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\src\rb.php:5340 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\src\rb.php(6049): RedBean_OODB->unboxIfNeeded('nick') #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\src\rb.php(9248): RedBean_OODB->store('nick') #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(17): RedBean_Facade::store('nick') #3 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\src\rb.php on line 5340
```

I required just `rg.php` and it looks like that it needed one or two thing .

Or is anything else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells explicitly where the error is hidden. RedBean expects a Bean object to be stored not a string. What should it store from a string, an empty row?

Please take a look at the Quick Tour giving you the insights how RedBean works.
[Quick Tour](http://www.redbeanphp.com/quick_tour)